# MySQL WHERE JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to search for a string in a simple JSON Array e.g.

```
'["Accounting","Administration & Office Support","Advertising, Arts & Media"]'

SELECT classification 
  FROM Skills.skills 
 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(classification, '$[0]') = "Accounting";
```

This work and returns all rows with `"Accounting"` in position **0**.

My understanding is if I were to use as wildcard `'$[*]'` then this would search all positions. However, this does not return any rows.

What JSON function should I use in this case?

Comment: _"However, this does not return any rows."_ - JSON_EXTRACT extracts the data _as JSON_ again, and the full array you got there, is obviously not `= "Accounting"`. How about simply [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) to search the array for the value:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM skills
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(classification, 'one', 'Accounting') IS NOT NULL
```

You can also use [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains), but you need to be careful to add double quotes around the string to make it a valid JSON scalar:

```
SELECT *
FROM skills
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(classification, '"Accounting"')
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5kAS44hkK5FbXjHjCvXxwK/1)

Comment: Ok, thanks. JSON_SEARCH appears to work perfectly.

Comment: @thepunter99 great, note you can also use `JSON_CONTAINS`, see my edit

Comment: OK, thanks again, this has been a great help.